# RealmQuery get records with null value also

Tags: android, realm

I have  RealmClass `ProspectGson` as,

```
public class ProspectGson extends RealmObject
{
    public ProspectMaster prospectMaster;
    public RealmList<ContactDetail>  contactDetails=new RealmList<>();
    public RealmList<DiscussionDetail> discussionDetail=new RealmList<>();
    @PrimaryKey
    public long id;
}
```

Class `ProspectMaster` as,

```
public class ProspectMaster extends RealmObject
{
     private long ProspectId;
    private String ProspectCode;
    private String ProspectName;
    private String TrustName;
}
```

Class `DiscussionDetail` as,

```
public class DiscussionDetail extends RealmObject
{

    private long RecId;
    private long ProspectId;
    private String    DiscussionDetails;
    private  String    CallPriority;
}
```

and my realm query is,

```
RealmResults results= realm.where(ProspectGson.class)
        .contains("prospectMaster.ProspectName", "abv", Case.INSENSITIVE)
        .contains("prospectMaster.TrustName", "xyz", Case.INSENSITIVE)
        .contains("discussionDetail.CallPriority", "High", Case.INSENSITIVE)
        .findAll();
```

I have many records of `ProspectGson` some contains more than one `DiscussionDetail` and some don't have any `DiscussionDetail`

I want to fetch all `ProspectGson`records which contains `DisucssionDetail` with `CallPriority`is `high` and  records which don't have any `DiscussionDetail`

Right now I am getting `ProspectGson` records which `CallPriority`is `high.`

Please help me out

Comment: please share your ProspectMaster and DiscussionDetail

Comment: @propoLis i updated my question

Comment: I don't really understand what you have, what you want to query and what you actually get

Comment: @EpicPandaForce simply, i want fetch records which discussiondetail is empty or discussiondetails-callpriority is high

Comment: Then the provided answer will do that yeah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RealmResults<ProspectGson> results= realm.where(ProspectGson.class)
        .isNotEmpty("discussionDetail")
        .contains("discussionDetail.CallPriority", "High", Case.INSENSITIVE)
        .findAll();
```

Please try it